# Определение функции внутри другой функции

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "clocale"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
    cout << "--- Settlement_objects ---" << endl;

struct Settlement {
    char name[32];
    int foundationYear;
    unsigned population;
    double area;
};

void Show(const char * prompt, Settlement * pObj)
{
  if (pObj == NULL)
    {
        cout << "(no object)\n";
        return;
    }
    cout << pObj.name << " foundation year:" << pObj.foundationYear << " area:" << pObj.area;
};
Settlement obj1 = { "Vinnitsia", 1355 };
Show("obj1", &obj1);
    //prompt, pObj->name, pObj->foundationYear, pObj->population, pObj->area);
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Пишет что после строки `void Show(const char * prompt, Settlement * pObj)`нужно `;`
Что не так?

Comment: @Igor Беда в том, что она НЕ пропущена, так сделано преднамеренно - `Settlement obj1 = { "Vinnitsia", 1355 };` - это часть `main`...

Comment: И как по такому заголовку посетители будут ориентироваться? Зашли за помощью - помогите и тем, кто после Вас зайдет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас эта функция оказалась **внутри** `main`...

В C++ нельзя определять функции внутри функций.

Но это не единственная ошибка. Например, `pObj.name` - так через указатель не обращаются, надо `pObj->name`.

P.S. Я специально не стал исправлять форматирование в вашем вопросе. Сравните свой код и этот:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "clocale"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
    cout << "--- Settlement_objects ---" << endl;
    struct Settlement
    {
        char name[32];
        int foundationYear;
        unsigned population;
        double area;
    };
    void Show(const char* prompt, Settlement * pObj)
    {
        if (pObj == NULL)
        {
            cout << "(no object)\n";
            return;
        }

        cout << pObj.name << " foundation year:" << pObj.foundationYear <<
             " area:" << pObj.area;
    };
    Settlement obj1 = { "Vinnitsia", 1355 };
    Show("obj1", &obj1);
    //prompt, pObj->name, pObj->foundationYear, pObj->population, pObj->area);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Согласитесь, что достаточно отформатировать код, чтобы причина неприятности просто бросалась в глаза? :)